# Cyclical graphs

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I have a question about cyclical graphs.

I understand that a simple cyclical graph is where one's edges and vertices are distinct.

Am I correct to assume that this means that no edge/vertex is visited more than once when completing a cycle? and that the opposite is for a non simple graph?

I would also like to know if having a graph with only say two vertices can be cycled through? or is there no need to cycle through a graph with two vertices?

For example:
Can you cycle through this?

```
A <-> B
```

Comment: *Am I correct to assume that this means that no edge/vertice is visited more than once when completing a cycle?* If that were the case then no, `A <-> B` would not be cyclical, as you could traverse from `A` to `B` but not back, as `A` has already been visited.

Comment: why is this tagged Java?

Comment: Good point. I was going to include java code, I will change it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If the graph is directed and is not a multigraph, e.g. `A -> B`, then there's no cycle, because you can only go from `A` to `B` and cannot go from `B` to `A`.
- If the graph is а directed multigraph, e.g. `A <-> B`, then its not cyclic, because `A` would have been already visited, before you try to get back to it from `B`. However, if you want to find a cycle of non-visited edges, then it would be cyclic, as you would track which edges are visited.
- If the graph is undirected, e.g. `A - B`, then there's no cycle, as `A` and `B` will be visited exactly once.